# asp.net is valid date

Tags: asp.net, validation

If the string in sValue passed in is **7.27** asp.net says its a valid date; which it isn't, its just a double in the data.  I need to ensure the string has a year and it needs to work for any locale 'date format', like m/d/y, d/m/y, etc. I can't seem to find a solution.  If it's real, then I am converting it to unix time which all works fine.

This is what I have tried, but as mentioned something like 7.27 passed to IsDate says it's valid (it returns July 27). Perhaps I need to see if the string has a year???

```
For Each myRow As DataRow In targetTable.Rows

            For Each myColumn As DataColumn In targetTable.Columns
                'is date? is unix? not then convert
                Dim sName As String = myColumn.ColumnName
                Dim sValue As String = myRow(myColumn.ColumnName).ToString().Trim

                Dim isValidDate As Boolean = IsDate(sValue)
                If isValidDate = True Then

                    'Dim oDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(myRow(myColumn.ColumnName).ToString().Trim)
                    Dim dte As String = TimeToUnix(sValue)
                    myBuilder.Append(dte & "000,")
                Else
                    myBuilder.Append(myRow(myColumn.ColumnName).ToString().Trim & ",")
                End If


            Next myColumn

            myBuilder.Length -= 1
            myBuilder.Append(vbCrLf)
        Next myRow
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 7.27 is a valid date - when you say that it needs to accept any format. If you don't want this to happen then in Javascript onmouseout you will have to check if it has a 'dot' and immediately alert or show an error and prompt the user to enter in acceptable format which you can then validate server side if you want.

Comment: July 27 is a month/day but without a year it doesn't help me.  Need to ensure that it has a year in the string; of which it could be in various country specific formats, something I don't have control over.

Comment: thats why i say you need to check it in JS first and then validate it in asp.net